# Create a new file in same directory where specific file exists

Tags: file, unix, sed

How do I create a new file, b.txt, in every directory where the file a.txt exists.

For example, if I have the following directories:

```
/boo --123.txt
     --1234.c
     --a.txt
     /aboo-- 12354.txt
          -- a.txt
```

then in both /boo and in /boo/aboo i would want b.txt to be created

How do I create a new file in different directory. If the file exists it should also create a new file.

I am using the command:

```
Touch workdirectory/filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this from your base path.

```
for d in `find . -name a.txt`; do  base=`dirname $d`;touch $base/b.txt; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
find -type f -name a.txt -print | sed 's/a.txt$/b.txt/g' | xargs touch
```

**Explanation** ([explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20-type%20f%20-name%20a.txt%20-print%20%7C%20sed%20%27s%2Fa.txt%24%2Fb.txt%2Fg%27%20%7C%20xargs%20touch)):

- `find -type f -name a.txt -print`: finds all file in the structure called `a.txt`
- `sed 's/a.txt$/b.txt/g'`: replaces the ending `a.txt` with `b.txt`
- `xargs touch`: and give the output as argument to `touch`, which creates the files